# Efficient Multiplication of Matrices with Large Numbers of Zeroes

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two arrays that take the following form:

```
    0…0…0 0 0 0…0        0…0…0 0 0 0…0
    ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮        ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮
    0…0 0 0 0 0…0        0…0 0 0 0 0…0
A = 0…0 1 2 3 0…0    B = 0…0 9 8 7 0…0
    0…0 4 5 6 0…0        0…0 6 5 4 0…0
    0…0 0 0 0 0…0        0…0 0 0 0 0…0
    ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮        ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮  ⋮ ⋮
    0…0…0 0 0 0…0        0…0…0 0 0 0…0
```

The size of the non-zero areas of `A` and `B` may not be exactly the same, but the diagram above is already getting a bit unwieldy.

Ultimately, the value I'm after is `sum(sum(A .* B))`. I feel like there must be a way to only multiply the non-zero elements, but every approach I can come up with seems to cause MATLAB to make a copy of the matrix, which utterly destroys any gains made by reducing the number of operations. `B` is reused for several iterations of the inner loop, so I can amortize expensive calculations on `B` over many loop iterations.

I've tried the following approaches so far:

Naive Approach:

```
function C = innerLoop(A, B)
    C = sum(sum(A .* B))
end
```

`innerLoop` takes about 4.3 seconds over 86,000 calls using this. (Based on MATLAB's "Run and Time" functionality.)

Shrinking `B` First:

```
function B = resize(self, B1)
    rows = abs(sum(B, 2)) > 1e-4;
    top = find(rows, 1, 'first');
    bot = find(rows, 1, 'last');

    cols = abs(sum(B, 1)) > 1e-4;
    left = find(cols, 1, 'first');
    right = find(cols, 1, 'last');

    self.Rows = top:bot; % Store in class properties for use in inner loop
    self.Cols = left:right; % Store in class properties for use in inner loop
    B = B(top:bot, left:right);
end

function C = innerLoop(A, B)
    result = A(self.Rows, self.Cols) .* B;
    C = sum(sum(result));
end
```

My hope with this approach was that MATLAB would realize that I wasn't writing to `A` and elide the copy, but this approach spends about 6.8 seconds in `innerLoop`.

I also tried only calculation the offsets outside `innerLoop` in the hopes that MATLAB might be able to pick up on the fact that I'm using the same subscripts on both matrices to optimize things:

```
function B = resize(self, B1)
    rows = abs(sum(B, 2)) > 1e-4;
    top = find(rows, 1, 'first');
    bot = find(rows, 1, 'last');

    cols = abs(sum(B, 1)) > 1e-4;
    left = find(cols, 1, 'first');
    right = find(cols, 1, 'last');

    self.Rows = top:bot; % Store in class properties for use in inner loop
    self.Cols = left:right; % Store in class properties for use in inner loop
end

function C = innerLoop(A, B)
    result = A(self.Rows, self.Cols) .* B(self.Rows, self.Cols);
    C = sum(sum(result));
end
```

Unfortunately this was the slowest yet at about 8.6 seconds.

I also tried looping with the following code:

```
function C = innerLoop(A, B)
    C = 0;
    for i = self.Rows
        for j = self.Cols
            C = C + field(i, j) * self.Sensitivity.Z(i, j);
        end
    end
end
```

I know that looping used to be very slow in MATLAB, but I've read some papers indicating that it is much faster than it used to be. That said, if the loop version ever finishes running, I'll let you know how long it took, but it's well over a couple minutes by now.

Any suggestions on how to optimize this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use [sparse matrices](mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and just do a standard A*B ? Sparse matrices not only save memory space, but they also benefit from specifically tailored algorithms like sparse matrix multiplication to avoid useless calculations.

Comment: @Gaporous. That is the answer. Put that into an answer block so that you can get credit for it.

Comment: "_if the loop version ever finishes running_" :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **sparse matrices** for this problem. Matlab handles different sizes of the «non-sparse-part» automatically. To get a sparse matrix, the `sparse`-function is used. After that you can do the element-wise multiplication and then sum all elements of `C` in a separate line.

```
A = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 1 2 3 0 0;
     0 0 4 5 6 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

B = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 9 8 7 0 0;
     0 0 6 5 4 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

A = sparse(A);
B = sparse(B);

C = A .* B;
sum(C(:))
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems I've oversimplified my problem, as this still does not improve the performance of my real code. Nonetheless, I this seems to be the correct answer to the question I actually asked.

Answer (score 4):

*This is a rewrite of my initial post*

I stand corrected. I don't know what went wrong in my former test. I thought it may have been a 32 vs 64 bit implementation of the sparse algorithm but not even. After careful re-running of the benchmark on 2 different machines, the `sparse` method wins then all.

[image: sumsparse]

Benchmark code:

```
function ExecTimes = bench_sum_sparse

nOrder = (1:9).' * 10.^(2:3) ; nOrder = [nOrder(:) ; (1:2).'*1e4] ;
%// nOrder = (1:30)*100 ;
npt = numel(nOrder) ;

ExecTimes = zeros( npt , 3 ) ;

fprintf('\n%s%5d \n','Calculating for N = ',0) ;

for k = 1:npt

    % // sample data
    N = nOrder(k) ;
    fprintf('\b\b\b\b\b\b%5d\n',N) ; % // display progress
    A = zeros(N) ;
    B = A ;
    innerMat = (1:10).'*(1:10) ;        %'
    ixInnerMat = innerMat + N/2 - 5 ; 

    A(ixInnerMat) = innerMat ;
    B(ixInnerMat) = innerMat ;

    % // benchmark
    f1 = @() innerLoop(A,B) ;
    ExecTimes(k,1) = timeit( f1 ) ;
    clear f1

    f2 = @() sum_logicIndex(A, B) ;
    ExecTimes(k,2) = timeit( f2 ) ;
    clear f2

    A = sparse(A);
    B = sparse(B);
    f3 = @() sum_sparse(A,B) ;
    ExecTimes(k,3) = timeit( f3 ) ;
    clear f3

    %// checksum1 = f1() - f2 ()
    %// checksum2 = f1() - f3 ()

end

end

function C = innerLoop(A, B)
    C = sum(sum(A .* B)) ;
end

function C = sum_logicIndex(A,B)
    idx = A>0 & B>0 ;
    C = sum(sum(A(idx).*B(idx))) ;
end

function C = sum_sparse(A,B)
    C = A .* B;
    C = sum(C(:)) ;
end
```

---

*<sub>All tests ran on Matlab 2013b

64 bit Machine : Intel I7-3820 @ 3.6GHz - 16 GB RAM - Windows 7

32 bit Machine : Intel E2200 @ 2.2GHz - 3GB RAM - Windows 8.1</sub>*

Comment: I get quite different results. Sparse is much faster. I had to use a log plot to even see the sparse times compared to the others. I also did up to N=10000. See http://i.imgur.com/k454hYt.png?1.

Comment: For me, running R2014b, `sparse` is clearly the winner: [graph](http://imgur.com/6wIdlNH)

Comment: In `C = sum(sum(A(idx).*B(idx)))` I think the outer `sum` is not necessary, because `A(idx)` and `B(idx)` are already vectors. Most importantly: use `idx = A & B;` (_and_, not _or_). This may save time

Comment: @Ramashalanka,  wow ... these results are so different I wonder if I did something wrong. I'll re-run the tests at work with a better machine (and i'll include Luis good comment (_as usual_))